# Codable for json response getting an error while parsing

Tags: ios, swift, codable

After constructed the codable, getting an error.

```
"msg": {
        "success": [
            "Successfully logged in."
        ]
    },
    "messages": []
}
```

// Constructed the codable for the parsing response data

```
    struct Msg:Codable{
   let success: [String]?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
    case success = "succcess"
    }
    init (from decoder: Decoder)throws{
    let value = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    sucess = try values.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .success)
    }
   }
```

I got this error when doing codable

**erro typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<swift.string, Any>. Swift.DecodingError.Context ( codingPath: [CodingKeys(StringValue:"msg", intValue:nil], debugDescription: Expected to decode Dictionary <String,Any> but found an array instead."underlyingError: nil))**

How to resolve this part based on server response.

Comment: Your json is not an array which the error message clearly tells you, you need a top level struct for msg, `struct Root: Codable {let msg: Msg}` and then use that when decoding

Comment: Be aware that you can omit both `init` methods and also the CodingKeys. And this can’t be the real JSON because it cannot cause this error. And if you’re responsible for the backend consider a better data structure.

Comment: Based on error description its says  CodingKeys(StringValue:"msg", intValue:nil]. Never see any intValue to asign

Comment: `intValue` is `nil` because the key cannot be represented by an Int. Anyway the error has nothing to do with `intValue`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson if forget to add { } the code inside.  Its shows valid json!  I do not have control on backend side.

Comment: There is no error if you implement the solution below properly  so revert your question to its first version and accept the answer below. _Edit: I did the revert for you_

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```swift
struct Msg: Codable {
    let success: [String]?
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let msg: Msg
}

let json = #"""
{
    "msg": {
        "success": [
            "Successfully logged in."
        ]
    },
    "messages": []
}
"""#

if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!) {
    print(response.msg.success?.first) // Optional("Successfully logged in.")
}
```

Comment: Always decode using `do-try-catch`. Using `try?` hides all possible errors.